# Define a 'head' for coinductive type stream in Coq(without pattern matching)

Tags: coq, coinduction

1) I believe that it is possible to use inductive types without pattern matching. (using _rec,_rect,_ind only). It is opaque, complicated, but possible.
2) Is it possible to use coinductive types withous pattern matching?

There exist a function from coinductive type to union of constructors' domains of coinductive type.
Does Coq generate it explicitly?
If yes, how to rewrite 'hd' ?

```
Section stream.
  Variable A : Type.

  CoInductive stream : Type :=
  | Cons : A -> stream -> stream.
End stream.

Definition hd A (s : stream A) : A :=
  match s with
    | Cons x _ => x
  end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is possible to use inductive types without directly resorting to pattern matching, this is only superficially true: the `_rec`, `_rect` and `_ind` combinators generated by Coq are all defined in terms of `match`. For instance:

```
Print nat_rect.

nat_rect = 
fun (P : nat -> Type) (f : P 0) (f0 : forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) =>
fix F (n : nat) : P n :=
  match n as n0 return (P n0) with
  | 0 => f
  | S n0 => f0 n0 (F n0)
  end
     : forall P : nat -> Type,
       P 0 -> (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) -> forall n : nat, P n
```

Furthermore, there are many cases where replacing pattern matching by an eliminator would result in a term with different computational behavior.  Consider the following function, which divides a `nat` by two:

```
Fixpoint div2 (n : nat) :=
  match n with
  | 0 | 1 => 0
  | S (S n') => S (div2 n')
  end.
```

It *is* possible to rewrite this function using `nat_rec`, but the recursive call on `n - 2` makes it a bit complicated (try it!).

Now, back to your main question, Coq does *not* automatically generate similar elimination principles for coinductive types.  The [Paco](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/paco/) library helps deriving more useful principles for *reasoning* about coinductive data.  But as far as I am aware, there is nothing similar for writing plain functions.

It is worth pointing out that your proposed approach is different from what Coq does for inductive data types, in that `nat_rect` and friends allow writing recursive functions and proofs by induction.  One of the reasons providing these combinators is that they are used by the `induction` tactic. Something of type `nat -> unit + nat`, which more or less corresponds to what you proposed, wouldn't suffice.